# How do I list the users from my terminal on my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, ubuntu-16.04

I want to be able to list all of the users from my command, but I don't know how to cut out

```
root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
```

etc. I want to list users with a UID of 1000 or greater. I know I can use that command `cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'`. Also, I would like to be able to sort by alphabetical order. I want only the users you can easily log into like:

```
alincoln
bclinton
bobama
dtrumb
gwashington
```

Thanks, Owen

Answer (score 1):

Try out the `sort` command,

```
cut -d: -f1  /etc/passwd | sort
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Does the 'sort' part do it in alphabetical order?

Comment: Yes! the 'sort' displays the users in alphabetical order.